# mCustomScrollbar and jQuery Content Panel Switcher conflict

Tags: jquery, panel, conflict

I have a problem with mCustomScrollbar and jQuery Content Panel Switcher.
Here's page screenshot so you now what I am talking about:
Screenshot

[image]
So the main idea was that when you click on any link in the menu (on top, with "Oferta" and so on) the content in the black(opacity 0.8) container would change.
I decided to use jQuery Content Panel Switcher for this and it works well.
But the problem started when I decided to use mCustomScrollbar.

On the page load everything works fine - you can scroll text in the container.
But when you click any item in the menu and jQuery Content Panel Switcher does its job mCustomScrollbar just disappears.

First I tried to enable `updateOnContentResize:true` in mCustomScrollbar but it did nothing

So I figured that I should use `$(".content").mCustomScrollbar("update");` and I tried to put it into jQuery Content Panel Switcher code, but even if mCustomScrollbar is showing it just doesn't work - you can't scroll text.

What should I do?